# How can I switch from one tab bar item to another in my Swift project

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a tab bar controller instance with 5 navigation controllers as its tab bar items. I want to be able to switch from one view controller to another navigation controller programmatically via the tab bar but I am struggling to understand how to do that or even if its possible.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
        guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
          let sceneDelegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate
        else {
          return
        }
        let tabBarController = sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
        guard let controller = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[2] as? UINavigationController else { return }
        controller.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2`